# C#: How to reference dynamic object properties in EF .Where() or Select() query?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to return a filtered list from an Entity Framework-Core DBContext, based on multiple query values POSTed to a .NET Core 2.2 Web API.

The API method maps `[FromBody]` to a `QueryObj` instance.

The `QueryObj` class has about 30 properties (mostly, but not all Strings). These are the "searachable" subset of the properties in the larger Entity (For example: "lastName", "serialNumber", "customerID", "purchaseDate", etc.).

Since the query options will likely change, and because it'd be clunky to write & maintain, I'd rather not hard-code ~30 comparisons like:

```
.Where(x => x.Prop1Name == query.Prop1Name && ... x.Prop30Name == query.Prop30Name);
```

But I can't figure out how to dynamically reference the properties inside a loop ... 
Or if a loop is even required, or ideal. Maybe it's not? I don't have any idea what the "idiomatic" .NET Core approach to filtering is, so if I'm totally off track, any advice is welcome.

In JS I could maybe do something like:

```
return myDataSvc.filter(x => {
  for (prop in query){
    if(x[prop] == query[prop]){
       return true;
    } 
  }
}
```

(this is likely wrong, but you get the idea - it's pretty simple ... )

In C#, the bracket notation for referencing object properties doesn't seem to exist, or at least what I tried didn't work.

The only answer I've found is a mess of introspection like:

```
x.GetType().GetProperty(prop.ToString()).GetValue() == 
query.GetType().GetProperty(prop.ToString()).GetValue()
```

Any ideas for a better approach?

Comment: If you want similar features to JS, you can use `Request.QueryString` as the input data.

Comment: There are many posts on building a `Where` statement dynamically. The usual and often best approach is using a predicate builder.